# Find Rally Workspace and Project OID

Tags: rally

This may seem to be a very basic question but I couldn't find it inside [Rally](https://www.broadcom.com/products/software/agile-development/rally-software), so here it is, where can I find the workspace and project OID inside rally?

Comment: I got the answer myself, closing this topic now.

Comment: How did you find the answer? I'm looking for this right now also.

Comment: I basically referred to nickm's previous post on someone's question and he had some code to get workspace information for each workspace, and it consisted of OID, so running the code gives me the OID of all workspaces, I will post the link once I get it.

Answer (score 6):

For the benefit of other users who may want to know the answer to it, here are a couple of ways of find OIDs. One of them is to create a custom page and paste this code in the HTML section:

```
<html>
Current Workspace ID: __WORKSPACE_OID__
Current Project ID: __PROJECT_OID__
Current User ID:  __USER_OID__
Curent User Name: __USER_NAME__
</html>
```

The custom page will display the OIDs:

Current Workspace ID: 11111 Current Project ID: 22222 Current User ID: 33333 Curent User Name: user@co.com

See [this help document](http://help.rallydev.com/create-custom-pages) on creating custom pages.

URLs of work items contain OID of a project where a given work item resides. In this example project OID is 2222 and the defect's OID is 7777:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/2222d/detail/defect/7777
```

Workspase OID can be copied from a URL of a WS API query. Go to

```
 https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/
```

and run any query. All queries are bound to a current workspace, and the resulting query URL contain workspace OID (1111 in this example):

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111&query=&start=1&pagesize=20
```