# In Rally how can get priority, severity drop list options using Web Services v2.0

Tags: java, web-services, rally

Like priority can be High,Low ,Medium.
As shown in diagram , get value of state drop down list etc in Json form
something like this

"State": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "open",

```
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "close",

    }]
```

Need this kind of values using web services V2.0[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may query on TypeDefinition object using Name attribute:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/typedefinition?query=(Name = Defect)
```

which will return a reference to the TypeDefinition:

```
_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/typedefinition/12352608495
```

Now if you use the ObjectID of the TypeDefinition you may get to Attributes collection:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TypeDefinition/12352608495/Attributes
```

Using "Defect" instead of ObjectID of defect type def will not work.

Now you get attribute definitions of defect TypeDefinition. Here is an excerpt from the response, related to State attribute:

```
{
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/attributedefinition/-12507",
        "_objectVersion": "1",
        "_refObjectName": "State",
        "CreationDate": "2006-02-11T12:29:05.000Z",
        "_CreatedAt": "Feb 11, 2006",
        "ObjectID": -12507,
        "Subscription": {...},
        "Workspace": null,
        "AllowedQueryOperators": {...},
        "AllowedValueType": null,
        "AllowedValues": {
          "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
          "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/AttributeDefinition/-12507/AllowedValues",
          "_type": "AllowedAttributeValue",
          "Count": 4
        },
        "AttributeType": "RATING",
        "Constrained": true,
        "Custom": false,
        "ElementName": "State",
        "Filterable": true,
        "Hidden": false,
        "MaxFractionalDigits": -1,
        "MaxLength": 128,
        "Name": "State",
        "Note": "State of the defect",
        "Owned": true,
        "ReadOnly": false,
        "Required": true,
        "SystemRequired": true,
        "Type": "string",
        "VisibleOnlyToAdmins": false,
        "_type": "AttributeDefinition"
      }
```

You can get the details of State attribute using this URL available from the response above:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/AttributeDefinition/-12507/AllowedValues
```

The Attributes endpoint returns the attribute definitions and allowed values for the default workspace if the workspace is not specified. The default workspace can be overridden with the "workspace" parameter.

Here is an example of getting AllowedValues for 'ScheduleState' in AppSDK2:

```
 model.getField('ScheduleState').getAllowedValueStore().load({
                                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(allowedValue) {
                                    console.log(allowedValue.get('StringValue'));
                                    });
```

You may see a full example of an app that builds a grid based on allowed values for Resolution field in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861941/how-to-build-a-grid-with-appsdk-2-where-columns-are-dropdown-values-of-resolutio).

For more details see [Rally.domain.WsapiField](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.domain.WsapiField-method-getAllowedValueStore)

Answer (score 0):

But when i had done the same thing i got response in which some of ElementName is missing like Priority,Severity etc. Any Solution on this.