# 403 (Forbidden): Access denied - When accessing RallyAnalytics - login credentials have admin access to Rally

Tags: javascript, rally

I am a newbie and started coding again after 11years. Please excuse me for my ignorance.

My aim is to get a list of defects from RallyAnalytics for all the projects in the workspace 10257115960d. The login credentials have admin access to the workspace and I have verified it by physically logging into the site.

The following is the URL I tried to connect to RallyAnalytics v2.0.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/10257115960d/artifact/snapshot/query.js?{"find":{"_TypeHierarchy":"Defect","fields":["State"],"sort":{"_id":1},"hydrate":["State"],"start":0,"pagesize":1000}
```

When I fire up the above request using GET/POST from a Google Chrome browser I get the following response:

```
“the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)”.
```

Any help to resolve this would be helpful.

Code Snippet....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     var rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/10257115960d/artifact/snapshot/query.js?{"find":{"_TypeHierarchy":"Defect","fields":["State"],"sort":{"_id":1},"hydrate":["State"],"start":0,"pagesize":1000}";
     var rallyUsr = "username@email.com"; 
     var rallyPsw = "password";

     xmlhttp.open("get",rallyURL,true,rallyUsr,rallyPsw);
     xmlhttp.send();

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like a valid workspace OID: 10257115960d. Please remove 'd'.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830709/find-workspace-an-project-oid) on finding ObjectIDs of workspaces and projects. In the URL below a workspace OID, and not a project OID has to be used.

Here is an example of a query:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/YOUR_WORKSPACE_OID/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_TypeHierarchy":"Defect"},&fields=["State"]&hydrate=["State"]&pagesize:1000
```

Paste this URL into your browser after substituting `YOUR_WORKSPACE_OID` with a valid ObjectID. If you are not currently logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser you will be prompted to login to Rally. Login to Rally, and see the query results.